MCMC samplers give noticeably different distributions--which is better?
Background
We have built two MCMC samplers to sample the posterior of a hierarchical Bayesian model with 4-20+ parameters. The two samplers use different approaches. For most datasets, they give nearly identical results (based on comparing marginal distributions). However, we have encountered some datasets where the results are noticeably different--the marginal distributions have the same basic shape, but are shifted somewhat, based on the sampler.
Question
What would be the best way to demonstrate which sampler generates samples that more closely follow the posterior? The proportional posterior likelihood is easy to calculate at any given point.
One idea
The one idea I've had so far is to use kernel density estimates to calculate importance weights for each of the two samples against the posterior distribution. The variance of the weights would indicate how well each KDE matches the posterior (low variance in the weights should correspond to a better match). However, if there is a better approach, I would be happy to have it.
Update in response to comments
As to the nature of the priors and posterior: The priors are all (proper) gammas, and the posterior is also proper. The reason for the second sampler was because the first had high autocorrelation in the hyperparameters, and so requires a very large number of samples. The second sampler uses a reparameterization that eliminates most of the autocorrelation. The datasets that give less well-matched samples also result in a mode at 0 for one of the hyperparameters. I strongly suspect the two things are related.
About the possibility of errors: The first sampler has been checked very thoroughly for errors, the second somewhat less so. Still, I suppose there's no guarantee, which is part of the reason for wanting to compare the quality of the samples--are the discrepancies because the first is a poor sampler in the general case, or because the second has a lurking error?

I don't have an overall answer, but instead of fitting a Gaussian mixture, it would be simpler to sample one sample from the chain then add a tiny bit of noise. Effectively, this samples from a kernel density estimator based on the chain. That way, you avoid the issue of the gaussian being a poor overall fit. Also, are you certain that there's no bug in there? That would be my first intuition

You haven't given us enough info to be sure, but different behavior with different samplers is sometimes a symptom of an improper posterior. Are your priors proper? Or are some of them uniform/etc?

If the same dataset leads to significantly different marginal posteriors depending on the sampler, there is clearly a convergence issue with at least one of them. You can compare the values of the prior x likelihood for both MCMC chains to check if they are reaching the same level (but be warned that a higher prior x likelihood value is not a criterion for a more likely convergence). You can also run sampler #1 and take its final value as starting point for sampler #2 & vice versa to check if the discrepancy persists.

@GuillaumeDehaene, you were right about the Gaussian mixtures, so I updated that part of the question. I haven't tried the KDE approach yet, but that's next.

@JohnMadden, I updated the question to add some more information. But, yes, all the priors are proper.

@Xi'an, I've thought about simply comparing the likelihoods of the samples from each chain, but I'm not sure what to do with the comparison. I guess higher likelihoods might indicate that the chain is getting "stuck" in a thin mode. I'll spend some more time comparing marginal distributions and the sample likelihoods more closely.

In my opinion, comparing marginal distributions can be very(!) misleading. My approach would be: first to find the maximum of the Posterior, for both cases. Next, integrate for the zeroth (!), first, and second moment for all parameters, possibly using the Laplace (Gaussian) approximation (far from trivial!). Then compare the "error bars": Sqrt[secondMoment - firstMoment^2]. And finally see whether you can identify some discrepancy. Good luck.

If it is not posterior impropriety, a related culprit is non-identifiability. This may be determined by Data Cloning (simply duplicating your data a bunch of times and seeing if the posterior concentrates or not); see e.g. https://academic.oup.com/sysbio/article/61/6/955/1665068

Data cloning that we proposed a few years earlier than Lele et a. (2002).
